# Sendgrid API with Alamofire

Tags: swift, sendgrid

I am using the Sendgrid API with Alamofire in my swift app. We are sending emails and everything is working find. With Sendgrid when a email is sent successfully, the response is nothing. Alamofire sees this as an error. Here is my code

```
switch response.result {
case .success(let value):
    print ("return email: \(value)")
case .failure(let error):
    print ("error: \(error)")
}
```

I get this when the email sends successfully. "error: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
did connect socket"

This makes sense of course since the response is nothing but we want to take actions when the email has been sent successfully. What is the best way to handle this? We do want to know if there is an error as well.

Comment: try to check if `response.response?.statusCode == 200`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: accept my answer then, might help someone else :) glad, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because there is not response, in this case you should check HTTP status code. If you are using Alamofire:

```
if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
    if statusCode == 200 {
    }
}
```